# Access emails using imap

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I am using Apache on Ubuntu 14.02 and running php on the same.I have connected to a remote mssql server hence no need of mysql .

I want to know how to connect to an email id registered with gmail in order to read the incoming emails .

I have tried the below , but it shows a blank screen while running it from my localhost :

```
<?php

error_reporting('E_ALL');
$mailboxPath = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX";
$username = "my_email@gmail.com";
$password = "mypassword";
$imap = imap_open($mailboxPath, $username, $password);
print_r($imap);

?>
```

I am inserting my actual gmail username and password while running the program . I want to know if i am missing something .

Many Thanks

Comment: What's the output of `imap_last_error()`?

Comment: 1) is your username and password correct? 2) change line `$imap = imap_open($mailboxPath, $username, $password);` into `$imap = imap_open($mailboxPath, $username, $password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());`. Now you will be noticed, why you can't connect into Gmail.

Comment: Hi ,thank you for the response ,below is my error : 


Cannot connect to Gmail: Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: http://support.google.com/mail/accounts

Answer (score 35):

Here is the solution:

1. Login to your gmail account, enable imap.
2. Let the access here first: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
3. Go to: https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
   and enable access.

That's it.

I had the exact same problem when I try to get emails with imap on php.
I was running the exact same script that I know it works with my other gmail.

The solution is above and the error message was:

> ERROR: Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser

Comment: And default IMAP settings are just fine when you enable IMAP on your account settings. If you have problems moving the messages, make sure English - United States is selected on your profile language settings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you activated the imap.so extension in your `php.ini` file ? `extension=imap.so` it's a basical cause of issues on localhost server

Comment: so you may don't have openSSL activated on your localhost

Comment: if it's not a ssl trouble, please log in to your gmail account with the link you've got in the error message a check if you have a message about a suspicious connection and validate the new client by entering your login and password

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you need to turn on your Outbound relay):

> 1. Log into your account at google.com/a/yourdomain.com
> 2. Click the Settings tab and then select Email in the left column.
> 3. In the Outbound relay section, select Allow users to send mail through an external SMTP when configuring a "from" address hosted outside your domain.
> 4. Click Save changes.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by google.com/a/yourdomain.com . I want to access a personalized gmail inbox . I do not see any settings or any tab to do with Outbound relay.Thank You.